# Using Base R to graph subset of data

Tags: r, plot, graph

I'm having trouble with my indoor trainer (bicycle) and I want to try to explore the data to see if I can isolate the problem. I'm not great with R generally, but I took a course in Data Visualization using R and I think I'm about half way to some excellent graphs. I'm hoping some tips from this community can help me finish it off. I know many people are ggplot proselytizers, and I respect that, but I think that this stage I'm trying to augment within what I know rather than trying to learn a whole new set of functions from scratch. I've included the data at the bottom.

```
mymindata<-load(file = "Indoor Cycling Data - Old.Rdata")
```

I don't seem to be able to subset my data when graphing, and because I have a long-form dataset it's giving me a graph which connects the last value in the first workout to the first value in the next workout.

[image: Wrapped Lines]

I would like to graph just one of these workouts by using a `subset` function on my `lines` function. However, my attempts at a subset function within the lines function are failing. I'd prefer not to set up  different dataframes for each workout. Is there a way to do this subsetting within each `lines` function? My failed attempt is in the line below.

```
plot(NULL, type = "l", 
     axes=F,
     xlim=c(0,100), 
     ylim=c(0, 60),   
     ylab="Speek (kph)", 
     xlab="Workout Time (as %)",
     main = "Cycling Speed over Time", font.main = 2
)
axis(2, col="black", tck = 0.01, cex.axis = .8, las = 1)
axis(1, col="black", tck = 0.01, cex.axis = .8)

lines(mymindata$time_pcnt, mymindata$speed, col="blue", lwd=1)
lines(mymindata$time_pcnt, mymindata$speed, mydata[which(date=="2021-01-21")], col="black", lwd=2)
```

### My data using dput

```
mymindata <- structure(list(date = c("2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", 
"2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", 
"2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", 
"2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", 
"2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24", "2021-01-24"), speed = c(22, 
26.7, 25.33, 27.85, 34.33, 40.31, 41.52, 46.66, 54.78, 58.75, 
47, 19, 27.91, 28.08, 28.22, 26.5, 28.28, 28.52, 30, 28.99, 29.89, 
20.73), time_pcnt = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Unformatted Workout", "Preset Workout"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset then plot, try:

```
# set up plot
plot(NULL, type = "l", 
     axes=F,
     xlim=c(0,100), 
     ylim=c(0, 60),   
     ylab="Speek (kph)", 
     xlab="Workout Time (as %)",
     main = "Cycling Speed over Time", font.main = 2)
axis(2, col="black", tck = 0.01, cex.axis = .8, las = 1)
axis(1, col="black", tck = 0.01, cex.axis = .8)

# all data, do not plot
# lines(mymindata$time_pcnt, mymindata$speed, col="blue", lwd=1)

# 21 Jan
with(subset(mymindata[mymindata$date == "2021-01-21", ]),
     lines(time_pcnt, speed, col = "red"))
# 24 Jan
with(subset(mymindata[mymindata$date == "2021-01-24", ]),
     lines(time_pcnt, speed, col = "green"))
```

[image]